# проблема такова . нужно реализовать рывок в юнити 2д. не понимаю как можно это реализовать

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class unit_controler : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animator;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    SpriteRenderer sprite;

    [SerializeField]
    int speed;
    public float jump;
    public int ExtraJumpValue;
    private int ExtraJump;
    public Transform земля_чекер;
    public float чек_радиус;
    public LayerMask что_есть_земля;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject хитбокс_атаки;

    bool Атака = false;
    public bool НаЗемле;

    public Transform upPoint;
    private bool сantStand;
    public bool сrouching;

    private void Start()
    {
        ExtraJump = ExtraJumpValue;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        хитбокс_атаки.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //проверка на землю под ногами
        НаЗемле = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(земля_чекер.position, чек_радиус, что_есть_земля);
        сantStand = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(upPoint.position, чек_радиус, что_есть_земля);
        //это движение игрока


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);

            if (НаЗемле == true && Атака == false && сantStand == false)
            {
                animator.Play("бег");
            }
                
            else if (НаЗемле == true && Атака == false && сantStand == true)
            {
                animator.Play("бег  и присидание");
            }

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(4, 4, 1);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);

            if (НаЗемле == true && Атака == false && сantStand == false)
            {
                animator.Play("бег");
            }

            else if (НаЗемле == true && Атака == false && сantStand == true)
            {
                animator.Play("бег  и присидание");
            }

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-4, 4, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
            
            if (НаЗемле && сantStand == false)
            {
                if (!Атака)
                {
                    animator.Play("покой");
                }
            }
            if (НаЗемле && сantStand == true)
            {
                if (!Атака)
                {
                    animator.Play("покой и присидание");
                }
            }
        }
        

    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && !Атака && сantStand == false)
        {
            if (НаЗемле == false && сantStand == false)
            {
                animator.Play("удар и прыжок");
            }
            else
            {
                Атака = true;
                animator.Play("удар");
            }
            
            StartCoroutine(Атакавать());

            
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && !Атака && сantStand == true)
        {
            if (НаЗемле == true && сantStand == true)
            {
                Атака = true;
                animator.Play("удар и присидание");
            }
            
            StartCoroutine(Атакавать());


        }





        //это все прыжок, лучше не трогать )
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && сantStand == false)
        {
            if(Атака == false && сantStand == false)
            {
                animator.Play("прыжок");

            }
            
        }
        if(НаЗемле == true && сantStand == false)
        {
            ExtraJump = ExtraJumpValue;
        }
        if((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && ExtraJump > 0) && сantStand == false)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jump;
            ExtraJump--;
            
        }else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)  && ExtraJump == 0 && НаЗемле == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jump;
            
        }
        crouch();
    }
    IEnumerator Атакавать()
    {
        хитбокс_атаки.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        хитбокс_атаки.SetActive(false);

        Атака = false;
    }

    void crouch()
    {
        if((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) || сantStand == true) && НаЗемле == true)
        {
            сrouching = true;
        }
        else
        {
            сrouching = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, что значит рывок? А во-вторых, у вас действительно в коде названия переменных на русском?

Comment: Писать на русском переменные - моветон, читабельность отвратительная

Comment: -----_____-----

Comment: Конечно можно на русском переменные писать, но если никто кроме автора код читать не будет, ну или если это 1С код. А here какой-то mix из two языков.

Comment: Если в `if`, `for` и т.д. не блок кода, а одна операуия, то `{ }` не нужны. Сотня строк мусора.

Comment: @кирилл распишите вопрос подробнее. Вам не смогут помочь, не понимая, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: вообщем. я первый раз писал код , поэтому много косяков .

рывок - резкое перемещение игрока в сторону (не телепорт), так чтобы еще и анимация была.
чтобы в  этот момент ни что не могло его тронуть (враги и им подобные).

рывок должен длится секунды 1-2.